# disabling the bypass key

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to disable the bypass key of my database on the open form event during the autoexec so that the user is not able to view the underlying tables of my form.  I have found the following code and creatd a module to run upon opening the form during the auto exec.  The module is called SetBypass

```
Call SetBypass

Option Compare Database

Public Function SetByPass(rbFlag As Boolean, File_name As String) As Integer
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    On Error GoTo SetByPass_Error
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(File_name)
    db.Properties!AllowBypassKey = rbFlag
setByPass_Exit:
    MsgBox "Changed the bypass key to " & rbFlag & " for database " &     File_name, vbInformation, "Skyline Shared"
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Function


SetByPass_Error:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    If Err = 3270 Then
        ' allowbypasskey property does not exist
        db.Pro  perties.Append db.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, rbFlag)

        Resume Next
    Else
        ' some other error message
        MsgBox "Unexpected error: " & Error$ & " (" & Err & ")"
        Resume setByPass_Exit
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Enhanced security Hans. I thought my explanation is quite clear. I would like to ensure that the user does not have access to the see the tables of the database.  By disabling the bypass (shift F11) this extra security measure could be achieved.

Comment: Thanks Hans your are right.  That is code that i would like to put in a module but I am not sure how to refer to it from the open form event on the form which opens via autoexec.   I tried using "Call SetBypass" but i get the error 'expected variable or routine and not module'

Comment: Aha!  Don't use the same name for the module and function.  Rename the module to *modSetBypass* and see whether any problems remain.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I updated the module as you said and changed the function to 'Public' (i think it is correct).. I am still getting however on the Debug 'Argument not optional' on the 'Call SetByPass' command

Comment: You must give the function 2 arguments: True or False for the first; and a text string containing the path to your target db file as the second.  So something like this: `SetByPass True, "C:\SomeFolder\YourDatabase.accdb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above module need to be called from out side the application.
Try the below code if you are in same database.

```
Sub blockBypass()
Dim db As Database, pty As DAO.Property
Set db = CurrentDb
  On Error GoTo Constants_Err 'Set error handler
  db.Properties("Allowbypasskey") = False
  db.Close

Constants_X:
    Exit Sub

Constants_Err:
    If Err = 3270 Then 'Bypass property doesn't exist

        'Add the bypass property to the database
        Set pty = db.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean _
            , APP_BYPASS)
        db.Properties.Append pty
        Resume Next

    End If
    MsgBox Err & " : " & Error, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation _
        , "Error loading database settings"

End Sub
```

Comment: but where do I put this code? On the on-open event of the form which is opened from the autoexec?

Comment: i used to give in switchboard (mainForm) form's Unload Event, thank you,

Comment: I am trying to use this same code and I keep getting an error on the APP_BYPASS variable what is this? Thanks!